# Combine file extension string and NSString in UIImage?

Tags: ios, syntax, nsstring, uiimage

What syntax would make this work?

```
    NSString *curstring = [cur description];
    UIImage *weatherimage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"@%.png", curstring];
    [weather setImage:weatherimage];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [NSString's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) stringWithFormat:

```
UIImage *weatherimage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%.png", curstring]];
```